# Css selector for an attribute whose value has whitespaces

Tags: python, css, beautifulsoup

I am writing code in python using a library_Beautiful Soup and I want to select this tag (using CSS Selector) :

```
<div>
...
  <div>
  ...
    <div style=" height:80px; width:700px; ">
     ...
```

I am trying to do:

```
soup.select('div div div[style*="height:80px; width:700px"]')
```

(The CSS selector is inside the single quotes i.e.

```
 'div div div[style*="height:80px; width:700px"]')
```

But this does not select any tag.

I have also tried:

```
 soup.select('div div div[style*="height:80px;"][style*="width:700px"]')
```

But this also doesn't work.

I am not allowed to do:

```
 soup.select('div div div[style=" height:80px; width:700px "]')
```

as it raises an error saying that this is an invalid css selector (whitespaces after the beginning double quotes or before the ending double quotes not allowed).

Can anybody suggest me the correct css selector for this tag?

Comment: could you add a codepen or something to demo your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `find`:

```
.find("div", style=" height:80px; width:700px; "))
```

Using multiple attributes in a select does not work with bs4, you are also limited to what you can pass when searching by attribute, the best you could do would be pick one `.select_one("div[style*=height:80px;]"` or `[style*=width:700px;]"`.